# How to Perform jQuery UI Function on Div

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, fadeout

I would like to find out if there is a way to perform certain jQuery UI function (e.g. fadeout() ) on particular DIV if all div has the same name.

The thing is that, the program output data into cast/mold DIV, therefore in HTML, it appears many div of same name.

Comment: can you lease post some part of your code..?

Comment: Name? You mean class?

Comment: you can give unique Id, or add special class for them!

Answer (score 2):

you can give a particular id to a Div:

```
 <div id="test">.........</div>
```

and apply jQuery to that div id as:

```
 $("#test").fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: He meant in question that he wants to use it for multiple divs. Identification by # is not proper for multiple objects.

Comment: @Robert : Agree. In that case your answer is correct.but OP question is not so much clear that same name of div means what he want to say ?

Comment: If my answer is okay why didn't you upvoted it :) I don't know either what he meant by "same name" :)

Comment: @RobertPodwika: I want but don't know at that time site prevent me to do this. now its done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery selectors similar to CSS that is why if you have multiple divs then you should use classes.

**Html**

```
<div class="mydiv">content</div>
<div class="mydiv">aaaa</div>
<div class="mydiv">bbb</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
 $("div.mydiv").fadeOut("slow");
```

this part of code affects every div with class **mydiv**

More about selectors you can find on [JQuery manual selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's relative position to the other divs you can use

```
$("div:eq(0)")
...
$("div:eq(n)")
```

Clearly giving each div a unique id is preferable, but if that's not an option, try the above

Comment: Thanks TGH, you have given cue on how to execute. I actually do a counter to identify the position of the div before removing.